# How to adjust valid input check method for SpinButton?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I'm using Office UI Fabric and have a SpinButton implemented. There is some kind of automatic validation that prevents me from using anything apart from numbers as an input. The problem is, I cannot even use the subtract sign. 
How can I change that?

I tried implementing my own onValidate() method, to cancel out the default one, and even though it's called, it doesn't stop the SpinButton input from being deleted when different from numbers

```
onValidate={() => console.log('Validate meeee')}
```

The whole SpinButton looks like this (it's mixed with JS):

```
static getNumericBox(formField: EntityFormField, onChange: EntityFormControlOnChangeType): JSX.Element {
        let rangeFrom: number = -999999;
        let rangeTo: number = 999999;

        const controlParams = EntityFormHelpers.getNumericControlParams(formField.controlType);

        if (controlParams) {
            rangeFrom = controlParams.rangeFrom;
            rangeTo = controlParams.rangeTo;
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment key={formField.fieldName}>
                <SpinButton
                    key={formField.fieldName}
                    className={'NumericBox ' + this.getValidationClassName(formField)}
                    label={formField.displayName}
                    labelPosition={Position.top}
                    componentRef={(component: any) => {
                        if (component) {
                            const inputElement = component._input.current;
                            const labelElement = inputElement.parentElement.previousSibling.firstChild;

                            if (formField.validation.isRequired && !formField.displayOnly) {
                                labelElement.setAttribute('required', '');
                            }

                            inputElement.value = formField.value;


                            inputElement.onkeydown = (event: any) => {
                                if (event.target.value.toString().length > rangeTo.toString().length + 1 && event.target.value.toString().length > rangeFrom.toString().length + 1) {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    event.stopPropagation();
                                }
                            };


                            inputElement.onkeyup = (event: any) => {
                                let numberValue = Number(event.target.value);
                                if (!numberValue) {
                                    numberValue = formField.validation.isRequired ? Number(0) : null;
                                }
                                onChange(formField.fieldName, numberValue);
                            };
                        }
                    }}

                    onValidate={() => console.log('Validate meeee')}

                    onIncrement={(value: string) => {
                        if (Number(value) + 1 > rangeTo) {
                            formField.value = value;
                        } else {
                            value = String(+value + 1);
                            onChange(formField.fieldName, value);
                            formField.value = value;
                        }
                    }}



                    onDecrement={(value: string) => {
                        if (Number(value) - 1 < rangeFrom) {
                            formField.value = value;
                        } else {
                            value = String(+value - 1);
                            onChange(formField.fieldName, value);
                            formField.value = value;
                        }
                    }}                    

                    value={formField.value}
                    min={rangeFrom}
                    max={rangeTo}
                    step={1}
                    onBlur={(event: any) => {
                        const numberValue = Number(event.target.value);
                        if (numberValue) {
                            if (numberValue < rangeFrom) {
                                onChange(formField.fieldName, rangeFrom);
                            }
                            else if (numberValue > rangeTo) {
                                onChange(formField.fieldName, rangeTo);
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                    disabled={formField.displayOnly}
                />
                {this.getDescriptionControl(formField)}
            </React.Fragment>);
    }
```

Comment: Could it be the `min={rangeFrom}` and `max={rangeTo}` parameters are causing the restriction?

Comment: @silleknarf Sadly no, the range is set from -999999 to 999999 and there can be a subtraction sign when I use the spin button arrows, but as soon as I type it, it disappears. It does the same thing with zero and letters

Comment: If rangeToFrom = -999999 then this line: `if (event.target.value.toString().length > rangeTo.toString().length + 1 && event.target.value.toString().length > rangeFrom.toString().length + 1) {` looks very strange as `rangeFrom.toString().length` is equal to 7 and `rangeTo.toString().length` is equal to 6. This means that the statement will always be true and therefore we will be stopping the entry with `event.preventDefault();                              event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @silleknarf Not true at all, this line is only true in case you manage to write a number that is longer, not bigger, thatn the proposed trange, eg you write 8 digits, it's tested and it's working

Comment: You're going to get pretty unpredictable behavior trying to combine rendering the SpinButton with React and manually messing with it through the DOM. If you list out the requirements for how you want the SpinButton's value restricted (and when onChange needs to be called), I can probably help find a better way to do it.

Comment: Also, it's weird that SpinButton doesn't support setting the `required` attribute, so if you file an issue about that we can probably fix it. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues

Comment: The problem is that it's not my code and it;s implemented in a large web app. It's definitely not written as it's supposed to be, but it's not my place or in my skillset to rewrite it all
However, I've managed to fix it and forgot to flag it, that's my mistake
Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the `onkeyup` methods. Everything kept overwriting as soon as a single key was pressed. A bit of fiddling around fixed the whole thing.

In case anyone is interested, here's the final and working state:

```
static getNumericBox(formField: EntityFormField, onChange: EntityFormControlOnChangeType): JSX.Element {
        let rangeFrom: number = -999999;
        let rangeTo: number = 999999;

        const controlParams = EntityFormHelpers.getNumericControlParams(formField.controlType);

        if (controlParams) {
            rangeFrom = controlParams.rangeFrom;
            rangeTo = controlParams.rangeTo;
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment key={formField.fieldName}>
                <SpinButton
                    key={formField.fieldName}
                    className={'NumericBox ' + this.getValidationClassName(formField)}
                    label={formField.displayName}
                    labelPosition={Position.top}
                    componentRef={(component: any) => {
                        if (component) {
                            const inputElement = component._input.current;
                            const labelElement = inputElement.parentElement.previousSibling.firstChild;

                            if (formField.validation.isRequired && !formField.displayOnly) {
                                labelElement.setAttribute('required', '');
                            }

                            inputElement.value = formField.value;


                            inputElement.onkeydown = (event: any) => {
                                if (event.target.value.toString().length > rangeTo.toString().length + 1 && event.target.value.toString().length > rangeFrom.toString().length + 1) {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    event.stopPropagation();
                                }
                            };

                            inputElement.onkeyup = (event: any) => {
                                const isValidKeyCode =
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.up ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.down ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.left ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.right ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.backspace ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.del ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.a && event.ctrlKey ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.x && event.ctrlKey ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.c && event.ctrlKey ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.v && event.ctrlKey ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.subtract ||
                                    event.which === KeyCodes.dash;

                                const isValidNumberKeyCode = (
                                    (event.which >= KeyCodes.zero && event.which <= KeyCodes.nine) ||
                                    (event.which >= KeyCodes.zero_numpad && event.which <= KeyCodes.nine_numpad)
                                );

                                if (!isValidKeyCode && !isValidNumberKeyCode) {
                                    onChange(formField.fieldName, null);
                                } else if (event.target.value === "-") {
                                    return;
                                } else {
                                    let numberValue = parseInt(event.target.value);
                                    if (!numberValue && numberValue !== 0) {
                                        numberValue = formField.validation.isRequired ? +"0" : null;
                                    }
                                    onChange(formField.fieldName, numberValue);
                                }

                            };
                        }
                    }}

                    onIncrement={(value: string) => {
                        if (Number(value) + 1 > rangeTo) {
                            formField.value = value;
                        } else {
                            value = String(+value + 1);
                            onChange(formField.fieldName, value);
                            formField.value = value;
                        }
                    }}



                    onDecrement={(value: string) => {
                        if (Number(value) - 1 < rangeFrom) {
                            formField.value = value;
                        } else {
                            value = String(+value - 1);
                            onChange(formField.fieldName, value);
                            formField.value = value;
                        }
                    }}                    

                    value={formField.value}
                    min={rangeFrom}
                    max={rangeTo}
                    step={1}
                    onBlur={(event: any) => {
                        const numberValue = Number(event.target.value);
                        if (numberValue) {
                            if (numberValue < rangeFrom) {
                                onChange(formField.fieldName, rangeFrom);
                            }
                            else if (numberValue > rangeTo) {
                                onChange(formField.fieldName, rangeTo);
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                    disabled={formField.displayOnly}
                />
                {this.getDescriptionControl(formField)}
            </React.Fragment>);
    }
```